# Take a value from the list and convert it to a enum

Tags: c#, list

I have a list with the following items.
Mistakes, Role and Name . In the database the Role is Integer . That is roles can be 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.
There is a enum class for Role 1= Reviewer1 2=Reviewer2 ..6-Quality Reviewer . I am aasigning the List value to the object. How can I take Role from the List and Convert to the Enum and assign to the object again . Here is the code sample

```
var result = new ChecklistLiability();
 result.CheckpointInstanceInfo = liabilityMapper.GetCheckInstanceInformationByIxLiability(result.IxLiability);
```

Result is the object.
liabilityMapper.GetCheckInstanceInformationByIxLiability(result.IxLiability); function will return a list with Role as Integer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast it, as in this example:

```
int roleAsInt = 1;
Role role = (Role) roleAsInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Enum.Parse and Enum.TryParse.

Casting does what you need but the .Parse methods are a little bit cleaner in my opinion.